# The top border of the table disappears using style "overflow:hidden" and "border-collapse"

Tags: css, firefox

Take a look at the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div style="float:left; overflow:auto; width:400px; height:300px;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:600px; border:solid 1px #999999; border-collapse:collapse;" ><tr><td>testing</td></tr></table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The top border of the table disappears in Firefox.
What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would add `table-layout: fixed;` to the styling

```
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" 
    class="width:600px; border:solid 1px #999999; 
    border-collapse:collapse; table-layout: fixed; ">
    <tr>
    <td>testing</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: I just change the code from class to style. The problem occurs.

Comment: Editted with another suggestion

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to remove the explicit `boder="0"` from the element, and see if that changes the display.